# Python memory usage reading files

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I was running a script and memory usage was increasing like crazy, so I wonder do python kill memory after each function when reading files.

So I did this:

```
import update_lib as upd
from time import sleep
import trading as td


def open_z():
    df = td.open_stock('poloniex/BTC_ETH')

while(True):
    open_z()
```

The memory is continuously increasing and script ends up eating all the memory.

Can you explain how can I prevent this from happening?

```
def open_z():
   df = td.open_stock('poloniex/BTC_ETH')
   del df
```

With del is the same problem~

EDIT:
The problem is not with the trading module because with this

```
import pandas as pd



def open_stock(name,period1='2000-01-01',period2='2030-01-01'):
    src= 'C:/Users/Araujo/Desktop/csvs/' + name + '.h5'
    df= pd.read_hdf(src,'table','r')
    return df.loc[period1:period2]


def open_z():
    df = open_stock('poloniex/BTC_ETH')

while(True):
    open_z()
```

The problem is the same!

Comment: How can I see that? I have 4gbRam and script stops at about 1Gb. The Hdf files have about 10-20mb of info
@JacobIRR

Comment: Have you tried closing the file before re-opening it?  Whatever is consuming the memory is happening down in the "trading" module.  You'd need to look at that code to see what's going on.  If you want to look into this you'll probably need to post a link to that code.

Comment: @bivoauc0 
Can you look at my edit? The open stock functions is that one, out of the module

Comment: Looks like the issue is with pandas.read_hdf().  A quick web search showed a few reported issues such as... https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16740 that you might want to review.  You'll need to talk to someone more familiar with that project to get help.  As a work-around, you could try importing you hdf5 though the library "h5py" instead.

Comment: I was looking  for it, can I open file with h5py and read it after in pandas??
All my functions are adapted to pandas. 

There is a way of clean memory after each use of object? @bivouac0

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm just using 
`gc.collect()`
It solved the problem.